# Having trouble spying on an action within a component test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, chai-enzyme

I'm trying to test for a dispatched action using chai-spies. I've tried various trouble shooting techniques, but have been unable to get the test to pass.

I've attempted to spy on both the `(component.prototype, 'method)` and `(wrapper.instance().props.store, 'dispatch')`, but have been unsuccessful.

Here's the component code:

```
export class Appointments extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.dispatch(fetchAppointments(this.props.user.id));
    }

render() {
    if (this.props.appointments) {
        const list = this.props.appointments.map(l => {
            let appointmentDate = new Date(l.date);

                let day = appointmentDate.getDate();
                if (day < 10) {
                    day = `0${day}`
                }
                let month = appointmentDate.getMonth() + 1;
                if (month < 10) {
                    month = `0${month}`;
                }
                const year = appointmentDate.getFullYear();

                let formattedAppointmentDate = `${month}/${day}/${year}`;
            return {
                id: l._id,
                date: formattedAppointmentDate
            };
        });
        return (
           <div className={"create-appointment-div desktop-hide-2 " + (this.props.isAppointmentInfoShowing ? 'hidden-1' : '')}>
                        <span className={"create-appointment-span " + (this.props.isCreateAppointmentFormShowing ? 'hidden-1' : '')}>
                            Need to create an appointment?
                        </span>
                        <button
                            className={"create-appointment-button "  + (this.props.isCreateAppointmentFormShowing ? 'hidden-1' : '')}
                            onClick={() => this.props.dispatch(chooseCreateAppointment())}
                        >
                            Click here
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div className="create-appointment-div mobile-hide">
                        <span className={"create-appointment-span " + (this.props.isCreateAppointmentFormShowing ? 'hidden-1' : '')}>
                            Need to create an appointment?
                        </span>
                        <button
                            className={"create-appointment-button "  + (this.props.isCreateAppointmentFormShowing ? 'hidden-1' : '')}
                            onClick={() => this.props.dispatch(chooseCreateAppointment())}
                        >
                            Click here
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div className={"create-appointment-form-component-div " + (this.props.isCreateAppointmentFormShowing ? '' : 'hidden-1')}>
                        <CreateAppointmentForm />
                    </div> 
                </main>
                <Footer />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    appointments: state.app.appointments,
    user: state.auth.currentUser,
    isCreateAppointmentFormShowing: state.app.isCreateAppointmentFormShowing,
    isAppointmentInfoShowing: state.app.isAppointmentInfoShowing,
    deletedAppointment: state.app.deletedAppointment,
    isMessageShowing: state.app.isMessageShowing,
    isLoading: state.app.isLoading
});

export default requiresLogin()(connect(mapStateToProps)(Appointments));
```

Here's the test code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {shallow, mount} from 'enzyme';
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {MemoryRouter} from 'react-router';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import chai, {expect} from 'chai';
import spies from 'chai-spies';

import Appointments from './appointments';
import NavigationBar from './navBar';
import Footer from './footer';
import AppointmentsList from './appointmentsList';
import AppointmentsShow from './appointmentsShow';
import CreateAppointmentForm from './createAppointmentForm';

const middlewares = [thunk];

const mockStore = configureStore(middlewares);

chai.use(spies);

const appointments = [
    {
      address: {
        street: '40 South Greenlake Ave',
        city: 'Jacksonville',
        state: 'FL',
        zipCode: 35421
      },
      _id: '5cb694034859fh37701f316e',
      description: 'Access evaluation',
      date: '2019-01-04T05:00:00.000Z',
      time: '2:15 p.m.',
      with: 'Jason Strickland',
      title: 'MD',
      where: 'Vascular Access Center',
      phoneNumber: '904-943-2942',
      patient: '5cb694034859f123701f3159'
    },
    {
      address: {
        street: '632 Oak St',
        city: 'Jacksonville',
        state: 'FL',
        zipCode: 34423
      },
      _id: '5cb694034859f123701f316d',
      description: 'Back pain',
      date: '2019-01-19T05:00:00.000Z',
      time: '12:30 p.m.',
      with: 'Jessica Brown',
      title: 'Primary care physician',
      where: 'Baptist Primary Care',
      phoneNumber: '904-233-1114',
      patient: '5cb694034859f123701f3159'
    },
    {
      address: {
        street: '402 South Lakeside Dr',
        city: 'Jacksonville',
        state: 'FL',
        zipCode: 35422
      },
      _id: '5cb694034859f123701f316f',
      description: 'Vein mapping',
      date: '2019-02-04T05:00:00.000Z',
      time: '2:10 p.m.',
      with: 'Jason Strickland',
      title: 'MD',
      where: 'Vascular Access Center',
      phoneNumber: '904-943-2942',
      patient: '5cb694034859f123701f3159'
    }
  ];

describe('<Appointments />', () => {
    let wrapper;
    let store;
    let initialState;
    beforeEach(() => {
        initialState = {
            app: {
                selectedAppointments: [],
                selectedLabResult: null,
                isSidebarShowing: false,
                labResults: [],
                isLabResultsInfoShowing: false,
                profile: [],
                loadedBasicProfileInfoFormData: {},
                isUserInfoShowing: false,
                section: 0,
                appointments: [],
                isAppointmentInfoShowing: false,
                areSublinksShowing: false,
                currentDoctor: 0,
                isCreateAppointmentFormShowing: false,
                isCreateDoctorFormShowing: false,
                isEditBasicProfileInfoFormShowing: false,
                selectedAppointmentToEdit: null,
                selectedDoctorToEdit: null,
                loadedAppointmentFormData: {},
                isDoctorMenuShowing: false,
                loadedDoctorFormData: {},
                doctors: [],
                areAppointmentsShowing: false,
                deletedAppointment: null,
                deletedDoctor: null,
                isLoading: true,
                animation: false,
                isEditAppointmentFormShowing: false,
                isEditDoctorFormShowing: false
            },
            auth: {
                loading: false,
                currentUser: {
                    _id: 1
                },
                error: null
            }
        };
        store = mockStore(initialState);
    });

    it('Should render without crashing', () => {
        shallow(<Appointments />);
    });

    it('Should simulate a click event when the button that renders the createAppointmentForm component is clicked', () => {
        initialState.app.appointments = appointments;
        initialState.app.isLoading = false;
        wrapper = mount(
            <Provider store={store}>
                <MemoryRouter initalEntries={['/appointments']}>
                    <Appointments />
                </MemoryRouter>
            </Provider>
        );
        console.log('props', wrapper.instance().props);
        const spy = chai.spy.on(wrapper.instance().props.store, 'dispatch');
        expect(wrapper.find('button.create-appointment-button').at(0).length).to.equal(1);
        wrapper.find('button.create-appointment-button').at(0).simulate('click');
        expect(spy).to.have.been.called();
    });
});
```

I want the spy to be called but I keep receiving this error:

```
● <Appointments /> › Should simulate a click event when the button that renders the createAppointmentForm component is clicked

AssertionError: expected { Spy 'object.dispatch' }
function (action) {
        if (typeof action === 'function') {
          return action(dispatch, getState, extraArgument);
        }

        return next(action);
      } to have been called

  300 |         expect(wrapper.find('button.create-appointment-button').at(0).length).to.equal(1);
  301 |         wrapper.find('button.create-appointment-button').at(0).simulate('click');
> 302 |         expect(spy).to.have.been.called();
      |                                  ^
  303 |     });
  304 | });
  305 | 

  at Object.called (src/components/appointments.test.js:302:34)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 11 passed, 12 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        6.625s
Ran all test suites matching /appointments.test.js/i.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
 // chooseCreateAppointmentFile - file from where chooseCreateAppointment is coming or 
 just spy on chooseCreateAppointment
 const spy = chai.spy.on(chooseCreateAppointmentFile, 'chooseCreateAppointment');
 expect(wrapper.find('button.create-appointment-button').at(0).length).to.equal(1);
 wrapper.update();
 wrapper.find('button.create-appointment-button').at(0).simulate('click');
```

In Unit testing you should isolate your component and then run assertions on provided inputs. You can just test if chooseCreateAppointment is called or not. No need to check for dispatch.